# Importing a module from node_modules that is not compiled to es6

Tags: javascript, webpack, node-modules

So we created a es6 module, put it in a stash and declared it as a dependency to another repository.

In package.json, we've included "search-service-redux-middleware": "git+http://stash.corp.web:7990/scm/blah/search-service-redux-middleware.git".

Which is fine, except that we get the following error when running the server:

```
Module parse failed: /blah/search-service-react-result/node_modules/search-service-redux-middleware/searchServiceMiddleware.js Line 1: Unexpected token You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import request from 'superagent';
| 
| export default (actionType, URL) => (store) => (next) => (action) => {
```

Which, as far as I can figure out, means that babel is not compiling all of the code to es6 - it's leaving out node_modules and using them as they are. So how can I make this work?

Here is the webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './app/index.jsx'
],
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'

    }]
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true
},
devtool: 'source-map',
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
]
};
```

Comment: Since `node_modules` is excluded from the loader with babel and your script being inside a `node_modules` directory, you should find the proper regexp to exclude `node_modules` but not `node_modules/search-service-redux-middleware`

Comment: So, I've changes the exclude line to `exclude:  /^(node_modules\/(?!search-service-redux-middleware)).*/,`. However, the error I'm getting now is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'WebSocket' of undefined`. I'm not exactly sure where that's coming from, as the output is in bundle.js

Comment: This is the line it breaks on, where global is undefined: `var WebSocket = global.WebSocket || global.MozWebSocket;`. So, some socket.io process is breaking?

Comment: Okay, so the way around this that we've found was to pre-compile the module and link to the compiled js file. It's a bit of a hack, but it works. Still not sure if that's the best way.